# VSCode workspace trust, how do I know if Workspace-Trust is affecting my extensions in anyway that blocks there functionality or preformance?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The **V.S. Code** team released ***["Workspace Trust Feature"](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/07/06/workspace-trust)*** in the ***May v1.57.1*** update, and then they updated it 3-4 weeks later in the ***"June v1.58.1"*** update. As it isn't important I won't go into details about what it does, but I will say I am happy that they implemented it. They only issue I have had is trying to figure out the extensions that it disables when it disables them.

*"Workspace Trust"* works in a tree-hierarchy type of system, for example:

> "If your root directory is trusted, all the files & directories in your root-directory will be trusted too, unless you configure Workspace Trust to do something else. Also there are exceptions, like dependencies, and folders like `node_modules`, which doesn't seem to be trusted when the root directory is.".

Configuring my projects to be trusted is easy, as I just explained above, however; when I am in a project that isn't trusted, like when I download an extension, and I want to view the content first, half my extensions seem to not work, as they are disabled, and it doesn't say anywhere which ones are. This causes errors, and frustration.

**So what I would like to know, is if there is anyway to tell when "Workspace trust" is disabling an extension?**

I assume there has to be a better way, than waiting to use the extension, just to find out the directory is not trusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, it has been several months since I wrote this question, and it didn't receive an answer because at the time there was no way to tell when Workspace Trust was disabling extensions, however, things have changed, and there is now an icon place by every extension that is disabled. As you can see in the image below.

---

[image]

---

I'm sure everyone noticed, but there are little shield icons next to the extensions that are disabled. When you scroll over them, to view the hover pop-up, you can clearly see the message saying that the extension, that you are hovering over, is disabled.